# Select divs with the same attribute from an Jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a grid of 6 divs with the attribute `row` which are nested equally between two divs with the attribute `col`. When the page loads I want to randomly select one of the rows and apply the class `.show`, so both divs with `row="1"` would be one `row`. From here, when the document is clicked I want one of the rows out of the remaining two rows to be randomly selected and have the class `.show` applied to it. When the document is clicked again, the last remaining `row` showed have `.show` applied to it. Now all three `row`s have the class `.show`. If the document is clicked again visual cycle should be restart so that only one randomly selected `div` has the class `.show`.

I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqxr1Lxa/4/) with the code so far. What I can't work out is how to select the divs with the same `row` attribute.

```
<div id="cnt">
    <div col=0>
        <div row="0">0</div>
        <div row="1">1</div>
        <div row="2">2</div>
    </div>
    <div col=1>
        <div row="0">0</div>
        <div row="1">1</div>
        <div row="2">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function selectDiv(){
   var notSelectedDivs = $("div[row]:not(.show)");

   if(!notSelectedDivs.length){
       $('.show').removeClass('show');
       notSelectedDivs = $("div[row]:not(.show)");
   }
   var randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
   $(notSelectedDivs).attr('row', randomIndex).addClass('show');
}


$(document).on("click", function() {
    selectDiv();
});
selectDiv();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The divs with the rows can be found by using the jQuery selector `[row=value]`. So with the random index: `$('div[row=' + randomIndex + ']')`

Quick example (upper bound for the rows hard coded for the example): [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqxr1Lxa/3/)

*edit* Example implementation:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

let rowDivs = $('div[row]');

function selectDiv(){  
   let notSelectedDivs = rowDivs.not('.show');
   
   if(!notSelectedDivs.length)
       notSelectedDivs = rowDivs.removeClass('show');
   
   var randomIndex = notSelectedDivs.get(Math.floor((Math.random() * notSelectedDivs.length))).getAttribute('row');
   $('div[row=' + randomIndex + ']').addClass('show');
}


$(document).on("click", function() {
    selectDiv();
});
selectDiv();
});
```

```css
#cnt {
  display: flex;
}
div[row] {
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.show {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cnt">
        <div col=0>
            <div row="0">0</div>
            <div row="1">1</div>
            <div row="2">2</div>
        </div>
        <div col=1>
            <div row="0">0</div>
            <div row="1">1</div>
            <div row="2">2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I understand how to do that, what i'm not sure about is selecting the a random row from the notSelectedDivs variable

Comment: The code you originally had was actually very close to doing that. Added an extra example with some slight alterations (such as buffering the rowdivs). Does the example do what you had in mind?